# How to generate same user id on firebase real time database and authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create login signup screens in React Native and want to fetch the details of user registered using signup/login. So far the details are getting stored in them but the user id in database and authentication is different in firebase in order to fetch them. How to fetch the user details from firebase if user id will be different in both the tables.

```
userLogin = (email, pass) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        .then(() => {
            navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            Alert.alert(err.message)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you login using the following the code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.user.uid);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

Here you can get the `uid` from firebase authentication, which you can then use in firebase realtime database:

```
var database = firebase.database();
 database.ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

Comment: I am new to React-Native and the one you suggested didn't work or might be I have done wrong. Can you post one more, I have updated my question with my code for login.

Comment: what didnt work, did u do `console.log(res.user.uid);`?

Comment: Oh Sorry, I used userId. When I used res.user.uid it did work, though, Thanks.